# SQL QUERY - check column has 'letter' or '-' then bring value from another column

Tags: sql-server

I have table 1 data and I need to create another column as on criteria

If id has "-" or "any letters" bring value from invoice

Table1

```
            +---------+---------+
            |   id    | invoice |
            +---------+---------+
            | 1234    |    2534 |
            | 9870    |    6542 |
            | ABC234  |    9874 |
            | 34-5469 |  325416 |
            +---------+---------+
```

Expected Result as id2

```
            +---------+---------+--------+
            |   id    | invoice |  id2   |
            +---------+---------+--------+
            | 1234    |    2534 |   1234 |
            | 9870    |    6542 |   9870 |
            | ABC234  |    9874 |   9874 |
            | 34-5469 |  325416 | 325416 |
            +---------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression and a `LIKE`.

Comment: what is the SQL Server version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use isnumeric function to find out whether the id is int or not.

```
select *,
case when isnumeric(id) = 1 then id else invoice end as id2
from [yourtable]
```

Edit: isnumeric is not providing credible results all the time and hence if you are using SQL server 2012 or 2014 and above you may go for try_cast

```
select * 
,case when try_cast(id as int) is not null then id else invoice end as id2
from [yourtable]
```

Comment: I don't recommend `isnumeric`. An `id` of `12e3` would return that value. If `invoice` is an `int` then it would error: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b851bdae3776506985959356a805de28)

Comment: @Larnu Yea agreed. Will edit my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming* that you are just looking for values that have a letter or a hyphen (`-`) you could use a `CASE` expression and a `LIKE` like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN id LIKE '%[A-z-]%' THEN invoice ELSE id END
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

What would likely be better, however, is to check that `id` doesn't value any characters apart from digits:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN id LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN invoice ELSE id END
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```